# Why can't I access static files that I add programmatically from a POST request?

Tags: c#, .net, api

I'm attempting to make a basic .NET API for managing a collection of media (images and videos).

I have configured the webroot to be a folder called "site", and within that folder is a folder called "media" where these files are stored. I can access a test media file that is saved in /site/media/Smush.jpg by loading https://localhost:5001/site/media/smush.jpg - this serves the image as expected.

I have created a method that receives a POST request containing form data from my frontend, and this method saves the file to the webroot using a filestream, code below:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("/media/add")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MediaAdd()
        {
            try
            {
                //get the form
                var form = HttpContext.Request.Form;

                //if there's a route, add it into the filepath, otherwise leave it out and have the filepath go straight to media (this prevents an exception if route is blank)
                string filePath = form["route"] == "" ? Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "media") : Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "media", form["route"]);
                
                //get the first (should be only) image - DO WE WANT TO BE ABLE TO ADD MULTIPLE IMAGES? PROBABLY TBH
                IFormFile image = form.Files.First();

                if (image.Length > 0)
                {
                    //check the directory exists - create it if not
                    if (!Directory.Exists(filePath)) {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
                    }

                    using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(filePath, form["filename"]), FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await image.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);                        
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
```

My frontend submits a route, filename and the media file, and this is used to save the image. This all works fine; I can submit an image with the path "test" and the name "test.jpg", and the API correctly stores the file at /site/media/test/test.jpg. I can view the file in the solution and see a preview of the image, as with Smush.jpg.

[image: Demonstration that the test file is added to the APIs local files correctly]

However, attempting to load https://localhost:5001/site/media/test/test.jpg results in a 404. Why is this the case? Can I not add files into the webroot through code and have them be accessible as static files as if I added them to the solution in my IDE? Are there any alternative ways of handling this?

I am using .NET 5.0, and have
`app.UseStaticFiles();` in `Configure()` in Startup.cs.

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find anything else like this.

**EDIT:**
On checking things again, it seems like rather than my files being at https://localhost:5001/site/media, they are simply in https://localhost:5001/media. I am not sure how I was able to access Smush.jpg at https://localhost:5001/site/media/Smush.jpg before.

It seems as though the webroot is not included as part of a URL to access files within it.

As it is now, I have got what I was looking for it to do.

Comment: I cannot comment on your actual problem since I'm not familiar with asp.net 5, but I'd like to point out that you *definitely* need to sanitize/filter your input if you start writing stuff into your web application directory. Just imagine, for a second, what would happen if a client crafted a request where `form["filename"]` is `..\..\bin\MyWebApplication.dll`. A malicious client could overwrite *any* file in your web application and, thus, execute arbitrary code on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

Well first a security concern as also @Heinzi pointed out...

```
string filePath = form["route"] == "" ? Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "media") : Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "media", form["route"]);
```

What if the user sends form.route == "../../" and instead of image he updates the appsettings.json file ?

Check [this](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal) out and have that in mind if you're planing to release this code to a production environment and make sure you only accept image files.

On the other hand if you are serving static files from a folder different to wwwroot please use [this configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will look into making things more secure.

Answer (score 2):

#### Why the 404

It makes sense. You are under the `controller/action` paths. Going under the site url the engine does the following:

When you request `https://localhost:5001/site/media/test/test.jpg` the code tries to find the media controller and the test action. It is not looking for static files on the filesystem. Since there is no such controller/action pairs, it will not find anything and thus return `404` not found.

If you saved the files in `https://localhost:5001/static/media/test.jpg` outside of the mapped routes, you would be able to access it.

Look inside your code for:

```
MapHttpRoute
```

Which is used to configure how to identify controller actions which are not decorated with the `[Route]` attribute.

#### Security concern

When you want to upload a file, you should consider a better solution and not one that accesses directly your filesystem.

Possible options:

- Blob storage on the cloud
- Database blobs

Don't forget to sanitize the input with an antivirs or some similar solution.

Comment: I think is not 100% accurate to say that "it's not looking for the static files", because he mentioned he is using the UseStaticFiles() Middleware, on the other hand using cloud or database blobs is not always the solution, he needs to fix his implementation rather than creating a new one.

Comment: That's a good point I hadn't considered - I have updated the routing to use api/media/add to avoid any mix up in addresses. I will look into blob storage - I have heard of it but do not know what it entails.

Comment: Static files are accessible via a path relative to the web root. So even with the `UseStaticFiles` it will not look for static files inside the configured routes.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras oh sorry, now I get it, maybe he has a controller route is conflicting with the static files route and its about priorities, amazing didn't think about it

Comment: The other two options are just that. It's not the right or wrong way.